# Client-side Google OAuth 2.0 stalling out in Instagram's webview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a working client-side javascript OAuth 2.0 package handling authentication through Google. But when I try to use it to sign up or login to my site from within an Instagram or Facebook webview, I get an infinite loading circle and a very tiny message: "One moment please..." —

[Screenshot of the tiny eternal loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VfqZ.jpg)

Looking into the problem, I see that Google is currently encouraging developers to switch to a web-browser auth flow, which seems to be what I have — https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-bans-logins-from-embedded-browser-frameworks-to-prevent-mitm-phishing/ — but I can't really tell what aspect is causing Insta to get stuck without throwing an error. The flow works perfectly within Twitter's webview, I should mention. It only seems to be the FB-owned platforms.

I'll include some of the front end code (React, using a "gapi-client" wrapper), because I don't think it's a backend issue. I am sending the token to my Django server to convert it eventually, but I think it's getting locked up on a redirect before that happens.

MOUNTING:

```
    gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "<CLIENT ID KEY>"});
      });
```

AUTHENTICATING:

```
const authenticate = () => {
      let gProfileObject = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      let scope = "profile email";

      return gProfileObject
          .signIn({scope: scope})
          .then((res) => {
                let username, googleResponse; 
                if (res.w3) {
                  googleResponse = res;
                  username = res.w3.U3;

                  localStorage.setItem("goog_avatar_url", googleResponse.w3.Paa);
                  localStorage.setItem("goog_name", googleResponse.w3.ig);
                  localStorage.setItem("goog_email", googleResponse.w3.U3);
                }

       //MOVES ON TO THE NEXT STEP IN THE SIGNUP PROCESS, COLLECTING ADDITIONAL INFORMATION FROM THE USER

       this.props.oAuthToggle(googleResponse.Zi.access_token);
       this.props.handleSpecialSubmit();
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
          )
    };
```

Has anyone had a similar issue with Google OAuth 2.0 on Insta or Facebook since the new changes were announced? Where did you seek a solution, and what did you need to change about your OAuth package to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @Harshit no we ended up changing our login methods, and by now i imagine all the packages and app ecosystems involved have changed significantly. The methods Alex highlighted below look promising tho

Answer (score 1):

Instagram browser doesn't support popups natively, it tries to swap windows, but sometimes crashes. So you can change google API behavior, set {ux_mode: "redirect", redirect_uri: "http://yoursite/url-to-redirect-after-google-login"} in gapi.auth2.init procedure.

But for now in Safari "redirect flow" fails. Finally I solved this problem by using "low level" methods like described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example
(see "OAuth 2.0 Endpoints" tab)